JMESPath return records based sublist of dictionaries
I'd like to select elements from a list based on the value of bar in the params key-value pair.  See example below.
I have the following code:
with open('foobar.json', 'r') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)
expr = '[].record'
records = jmespath.search(expr, data)

And the following input file (foobar.json)
[   {   'record': {   'name': 'foobar1',
                      'params': [   {'name': 'foo', 'text': '4'},
                                    {'name': 'bar', 'text': '12'}]}},
    {   'record': {   'name': 'foobar2',
                      'params': [   {'name': 'foo', 'text': '4'},
                                    {'name': 'bar', 'text': '16'}]}}]

The JMESPath query returns both records, as expected.
[   {   'name': 'foobar1',
        'params': [   {'name': 'foo', 'text': '4'},
                      {'name': 'bar', 'text': '12'}]},
    {   'name': 'foobar2',
        'params': [   {'name': 'foo', 'text': '4'},
                      {'name': 'bar', 'text': '16'}]}]

I'd like a JMESPath expression that would return only this one record because the text of the entry in params with name bar is greater than or equal to 13.
[   {   'name': 'foobar2',
        'params': [   {'name': 'foo', 'text': '4'},
                      {'name': 'bar', 'text': '16'}]}]


There is nothing blocking you to make n-levels filter projections in JMESPath.
So, here, what you are looking for is all element where you will filter the record.params array (first level filter projection) where its elements contains a text greater or equal than thirteen and the name is bar (second level filter projection).
Which will translate in the query
[?record.params[?to_number(text) >= `13` && name == `bar`]].record

You just. have to feed this in your expr variable to get your desired result.

This would also find cases where foo is equal to 13.  I wan't only cases where bar is equal to 13.

Oh, my bad, I didn't saw that in your question, added the correct &&, then.

Put the query into a comprehension. For example,
import json
import jmespath

fp = open('foobar.json', 'r')
data = json.load(fp)
result = [i for i in data if int(jmespath.search('[?name==`bar`].text', i['record']['params'])[0]) >= 13]
print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))

gives
[
    {
        "record": {
            "name": "foobar2",
            "params": [
                {
                    "name": "foo",
                    "text": "4"
                },
                {
                    "name": "bar",
                    "text": "16"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]

